# Inconsistencies found in exp_channel_titles and exp_channel_data tables

Tags: channel

While I was looking into a related issue, I found the following scenario:
Entry IDs in the exp_channel_data table do not match entry IDs in the exp_channel_titles table. I want to clean these up so there are no inconsistencies. **Any suggestions as to how to clean this up?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this query in you SQL browser/tool/contraption of choice.

```
SELECT exp_channel_data.entry_id, exp_channel_titles.entry_id
FROM exp_channel_data
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_channel_titles.entry_id IS NULL
```

This will give you a list of entries in your exp_channel_data table that don't have a title row. you can reverse the query to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean that there are some entries in the channel data table but not in the channel  titles table, then you can probably delete them (make a backup first!) I've never seen this myself and cannot think of a scenario where this might occur so cannot give you a exact definitive answer i'm afraid.

But certainly try what i've suggested, see if it causes any issues and make sure you have that backup just in case!